# python regular express extract certain words from a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a long string below,

> 'Elevation Info:Elevation range:\xa05680 - 5720
>   ft\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(40-foot closed contour) NAVD88 Elevation:\xa05683
>   ft / 1732 m\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(Range 5683 - 5723 ft)Latitude/Longitude
>   (WGS84)32° 56\' 17\'\' N, 116° 29\' 9\'\' W32.938182, -116.485858 (Dec
>   Deg)548063 E 3644551 N, Zone 11 (UTM)Country**United
>   States**State/Province**California (Highest Point)**
>   County/Second Level Region**San
>   Diego**LinksSearch Engines - search the web for "Garnet Mountain"'

And I want to obtain the words 'United States' ,'California (Highest Point)', 'San Diego' by using regular expression.

I tired to find 'United State' & 'San Diego' by the codes below but the result is empty

```
country = re.findall(('Country\S([A-z]*)\SState'),table.text)
country
region = re.findall(('Region\S(.)\SLinks'),table.text)
region
```

How could I using re to extract all these words?

Also, if the 'United States' are replace by eg.'Japan'/'France'

```
country = re.findall(('Country\S([A-z]*)\SState'),table.text)
country
```

The output is 'apan' / 'rance'. Why they are not a full word.

Thank You!

Comment: Please tell us what the encoding of your Python script is.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen it should be utf8

Comment: The group (the part in paranthesis) won't match if a whitespace is in the country `([A-z]*)` and it matches only one char `(.)` for Region. `\S` matches any character which is not a whitespace character and you did not include it in your group so the first char is cut (the last is not because it is a "greedy" match).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import re

str = "'Elevation Info:Elevation range:\xa05680 - 5720 ft\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(40-foot closed contour) NAVD88 Elevation:\xa05683 ft / 1732 m\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(Range 5683 - 5723 ft)Latitude/Longitude (WGS84)32° 56\' 17\'\' N, 116° 29\' 9\'\' W32.938182, -116.485858 (Dec Deg)548063 E 3644551 N, Zone 11 (UTM)CountryUnited StatesState/ProvinceCalifornia (Highest Point) County/Second Level RegionSan DiegoLinksSearch Engines - search the web for \"Garnet Mountain'\""

country = re.findall(r"Country(\S*.*)State/", str)
province = re.findall(r"Province(\S*.*)County/", str)
city= re.findall(r"Region(\S*.*)Links", str)

print(country[0])
print(province[0])
print(city[0])
print("--------")
```

Also, you can probably omit using regex altogether, with `Split()`:

```
country = str.split("Country")[1].split("State/")[0]
province = str.split("Province")[1].split("County/")[0]
city = str.split("Region")[1].split("Links")[0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have one more question, could you get 'California (Highest Point)' for the province? I can only get 'California' in my computer.

Comment: @goxywood - Are you using the code and string as I have above? I get `California (Highest Point)` on my output, with both methods (`regex` and `split()`).

Comment: Thank you very much! I can get the whole string now!

Answer (score 0):

`\S*` Matches zero or more non-whitespace characters. You don't need that here.

Use `.*` (zero or more non-newline characters) instead or explicitly say what characters you want.

E.g. `[A-z0-9 ()]*` would only allow letters, numbers, spaces and parantheses.

To strip whitespaces before or after, you can add `\s*` (small `s`) outside your group and make your `*` non-greedy with a question mark: `\s*(.*?)\s*`.

All together:

```
import re

str = "'Elevation Info:Elevation range:\xa05680 - 5720 ft\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(40-foot closed contour) NAVD88 Elevation:\xa05683 ft / 1732 m\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(Range 5683 - 5723 ft)Latitude/Longitude (WGS84)32° 56\' 17\'\' N, 116° 29\' 9\'\' W32.938182, -116.485858 (Dec Deg)548063 E 3644551 N, Zone 11 (UTM)CountryUnited StatesState/ProvinceCalifornia (Highest Point) County/Second Level RegionSan DiegoLinksSearch Engines - search the web for \"Garnet Mountain'\""

countries = re.findall(r"Country\s*(.*?)\s*State/", str)
provinces = re.findall(r"Province\s*(.*?)\s*County/", str)
regions = re.findall(r"Second Level Region\s*(.*?)\s*Links", str)

print("Countries:")
for country in countries:
  print(" ", country)

print("Provinces:")
for province in provinces:
  print(" ", province)

print("Second Level Regions:")
for region in regions:
  print(" ", region)
```

You can play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/yeiJVg/1

Or you can group them all together to find multiple groups in a bigger string:

```
import re

str = "'Elevation Info:Elevation range:\xa05680 - 5720 ft\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(40-foot closed contour) NAVD88 Elevation:\xa05683 ft / 1732 m\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(Range 5683 - 5723 ft)Latitude/Longitude (WGS84)32° 56\' 17\'\' N, 116° 29\' 9\'\' W32.938182, -116.485858 (Dec Deg)548063 E 3644551 N, Zone 11 (UTM)CountryUnited StatesState/ProvinceCalifornia (Highest Point) County/Second Level RegionSan DiegoLinksSearch Engines - search the web for \"Garnet Mountain'\""

matches = re.findall(r"Country\s*(.*?)\s*State/[.*\n]*Province\s*(.*?)\s*County/[.*\n]*Second Level Region\s*(.*?)\s*Links", str)

for match in matches:
    print("Country: {}, Province: {}, Second Level Region: {}".format(*match))
```